#  primes of the form $a^n+b^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory

if $p =4k+1$, then p has the form $a^2+b^2$. My question: is there $p=kn+h$ with $gcd(k,h)=1$, such that for significant $k$ and $h$, and $n_1$ , $p=a^{n_1} + b^{n_1}$ ($k>2$, $h>1$, $n_1>2$).

Comment: I feel that the quality of the answers below does not match the quality of the original question. "Stone soup".

Comment: Of course, since I am not a number theorist in any reasonable sense, I may be misjudging the question; though I would invite those who disagree to look through a series of questions raised by the same user.

Answer (score 7):

Primes of that form are very rare for n > 2 so you can't expect that they fill an arithmetic progression. Heath-Brown proved that there are infinitely many primes which are sums of two cubes. The proof is hard.

See corrections below...

EDIT, Will Jagy. Evidently Felipe posted from an ipod and was not able to edit at length. He will be able to fix everything when we he settles down his weary feet from his current travels. He meant the bit about such primes being rare. From his comment, it seems most likely that he meant to say originally that there are infinitely many primes of shape $$ x^3 + 2 y^3.$$

Moving on to Victor's comment, primes of shape $ a^3 + b^3$ actually solve
$ p = 3 a^2 - 3 a + 1.$ This means that the number of such primes up to some large positive $M$ is at most $$ c_4 \sqrt M$$ which is asymptotically much less than the number of primes up to the same $M$ in some arithmetic progression, that being $$ c_5 \frac{M}{\log M}  $$
So, infinitely many primes, indeed a set of full density, fail to have such an expression.

Finally, it would be a remarkable thing if it were known that there were infinitely many such primes. We certainly do not know the status for primes $n^2 + 1.$ Indeed, I am moved to ask: is there  any polynomial in one variable, integer coefficients, and degree at least two that is known to represent infinitely many primes?

He then gives a link to the Friedlander-Iwaniec theorem, maybe I have it right.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander%E2%80%93Iwaniec_theorem

For Felipe, Whenever We May Find Him: $$ $$
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buMH_tAu2Zg

Comment: So the answer to the question which I think he is trying to ask is "no".

Comment: @felipe, i am not follow about on word no,if everbody ask question in MO,he want to hear complete answer ,no one word

Comment: Since $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ and the second factor is $((a+b)^2+3(a-b)^2)/4,$ the number $p=a^3+b^3$ can only be prime (and positive) if $b=1-a.$ That translates into "$p=3a^2-3a+1$ is prime".  

Comment: n^3 + m^3 has n+m as a proper factor for most pairs (m,n).  Does Heath-Brown have a proof for pairs other than (n+1, -n)?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.08.11

Comment: "if everbody ask question in MO,he want to hear complete answer ,no one word". I can't speak for anyone else, but I would like questions on MO to give more evidence that the questioner has thought *seriously* about the question which they ask. "I do not understand X", or "I wonder if there is X", is in my view *not enough*.

Comment: $x^3+2y^3$ I am not paying attention to what I am writing, sorry.

Comment: See also http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander–Iwaniec_theorem

Comment: Posting on MO from an iPod doesn't work. Thanks to Will for his detailed answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer to Will Jagy's question about polynomials of degree at least 2 is no, no such polynomial in one variable has been proved to represent infinitely many primes. 

Comment: @ yemon,the question is suitable for MO or not,if not  it should be closed and nobody answer to it and take positive vote,otherwise taking negative vote is not resonable.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. Hashem, you have it backwards. You are asking people who know more than you to provide answers to questions when you never write more than two sentences, never explain how much or how little you already know, and show very little indication that you have done any work at all. Among many other things, this is not really a tutoring center. If you are the one asking an MO question, *you are expected to do more work than the people answering.* 

Comment: I am reading Hashem's comment as an invitation to either upvote or vote to close. I choose the latter.

Answer (score 4):

As Felipe and Victor indicate, the case $n=3$ is a little special. For $n \geq 4,$ the total number of values, prime or not, with $$ a^n + b^n \leq M  $$ is at most $$  c_1 \; M^{2/n}$$ when 
$a,b \geq 0.$ Then the factorization
$$ a^n - b^n = ( a - b) ( a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b + \ldots + a b^{n-2} + b^{n-1} )$$
shows that, with $a \neq b,$ we have $| a - b | \geq 1$ and this time we are demanding $a^{n-1} + b^{n-1} \leq M,$ so the count up to $M$ is at most $$  c_2 \; M^{2/(n-1)}$$ 
But the number of primes in an arithmetic progression is 
$$ c_3 \; \frac{M}{\log M} $$
which is asymptotically larger, so there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression that have no such expression.